# I need help overloading constructors and creating constructors that accept classes as arguments

Tags: java, class, constructor, class-constructors

My code has been taken from my previous Lab where we calculated the distance between two coordinates entered by the user. How can I create an overloaded constructor that accepts Coordinates as an argument?

```
public class airport {

    private static double PI = 3.14159;
    private static double earthRadius = 10800 / PI;
    private static double distance;
    private static double deltaChange;

    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        coordinates pointA = new coordinates(Lat1, Long1);
        coordinates pointB = new coordinates(Lat2, Long2);

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Coordinates prompted/entered
        System.out.print("Enter your coordinates: \n");
        System.out.print("Lat 1: ");
        double Lat1 = stdin.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Long 1: ");
        double Long1 = stdin.nextDouble();

        // Coordinates(2) prompted/entered
        System.out.print("Lat 2: ");
        double Lat2 = stdin.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Long 2: ");
        double Long2 = stdin.nextDouble();

    }

    public airport(double a, double b) {
        this.Lat1 = a;
        this.Long1 = b;
    }

    public airport(double a, double b) {
    }

    public airport() {
    }


    }

}
```

```
public class coordinates {

    coordinates(double x, double y)
    {
        this.latitude = x;
        this.longitude = y;
    }

    private double latitude = 0;
    private double longitude = 0;



    //mutator
    public void setLat(double lat)
    {
        this.latitude = lat;
    }
    public void setLong(double lon)
    {
        this.longitude = lon;
    }

    public double getLat()
    {
        return latitude;
    }
    public double getLong()
    {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh and "import myPackage.myclass" is not working.

Comment: Well, heads up I wasn't "saving" my coordinates file after every edit so now my coordinate object PointA and PointB are working lol lesson learned there. Still need help though.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should edit any extra info (your comments) into the question itself. I recommend that you not copy and paste your entire assignment here. Put *the specific problem* into your own words, or people might assume you want answers for homework (which is frowned upon here) and turn away. Questions should be about specific problems, possibly 1 question for each problem unless they are contextual (that does not mean from the same assignment). Check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).